# Android bubble sms

Tags: android, sms

I am working on android chat application. I need to use bubbles for chat sms. Is there any working example for this. It will be of great use if someone who have worked on such applications can guide me with few working examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This Tutorial will help you:
Custom adapter for ListView to create bubble shaped list rows
[see this link](http://thetechnib.blogspot.com/2010/12/android-tutorial-custom-adapter-for.html)

you always should understand the 9-patch drawable
[9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html)

Hope this will help you